# A number of Form $6k+5$ is also of form $3k+2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Is the following Proof Correct?

> **Theorem.** Every Integer of the form $6k+5$ is also of the form $3j+2$.

**Proof.** Let $n$ be an arbitrary integer and assume that for some $k\in\mathbf{Z}$, $n=6k+5$ and that $n$ does not have the form $3k+2$ then by the  the division algorithm it must be that either $n = 3q_1$ or $n=3q_2+2$ for some integers $q_1$ and $q_2$, examining both cases below we see that

*Case-1$(n=3q_1)$:* $ 6k+5=3q_1$ and by extension $5 = 3(q_1-2k)$ but $3\not|5$

*Case-2$(n=3q_2+1)$:* $6k+5=3q_2+1$ and by extension $4 = 3(q_2-2k)$ but $3\not|4$

Consequently by the division algorithm it must be that $n=3j+2$ for some $j\in\mathbf{Z}$.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write $$6k+5=3(2k+1)+2.$$

Comment: wow suckerpunch

Comment: @Atif Farooq But since $2k+1$ id odd, the reversed statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  reframe it as "*every integer of the form $6k-1$ is also of the form $3j-1$*".